# Why do browsers use so much memory?

Tags: memory, browser

Firefox with 18 tabs open = 1.34GB of memory (~75MB/tab).

Got a reply on twitter from another local developer mentioning his Chrome instance was using ~82MB/tab.

What causes web browsers to consume that much memory?

Comment: The actual content of web pages is only a few megabytes at most, right?  Why do web browsers consistently use >1 GB of RAM?  Why would tabs use any memory if they're not actually loaded?

Answer (score 5):

To make it more crash-resistant, Chrome spawn many copies of itself as full-fledged processes instead of simply using multi-threading. This clearly eats more memory (less things can be shared). Chrome puts the plugins in separate processes (so that a crash of Flash won't bring down the whole browser)... Other memory consumed... And so on.

Comment: Other browsers consume huge amounts of memory, too, though.  Firefox takes up gigabytes without spawning any new processes